# How to set database connection of .rpt dynamically

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I don't know how to ask this question thru google, i try but what i've got is not what I want so i decided to post it here.

Currently i'm developing a crystal report for a particular web application. Now i manage to display my report in my development environment, once i deploy the web app and i want to show my report it always display this window.

[image]

I don't want to modify those .rpt again to adjust on the current database i want to do it in code, specifically in c sharp. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're hosting the controls yourself -- this post should provide you what you're looking for.  If not I'll need you to provide me a bit more information surrounding your solution.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/7345fc6c-9749-42a3-b866-509c57f3cc35/